# Updating macros in a C file using perl

Tags: c, regex, file, perl

I want to update a release number in a C file where it is present in the form of a macro. I want to implement this in perl.
I have done a small implementation but I'm eager to understand if this is the right solution or it can be optimsed further.

The C file (input file: test_file.c) is as given below:

**INPUT_FILE** (test_file.c)

```
#include "header_file.h"

#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION    100
#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION    20
#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION      1
#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION      2
#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION    3

#if ((ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION != SOME_VERSION) || \
     (ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION != SOME_OTHER_VERSION))
#error Versions do not match
    typedef int fix_this_compiler_error;
#else
    typedef int fix_this_compiler_error;
#endif
```

Lets say that the release number is `101p1p2p3p4`, I want to split this release number and update the macros in the C file as shown below:

```
#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION    101
#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION     1
#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION      2
#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION      3
#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION    4
```

Here in the release number `101p1p2p3p4` the value after every `p` is a major/minor version for the release and same needs to be updated in the C file. So the desired output look something like this:

**DESIRED_OUTPUT**

```
#include "header_file.h"

#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION    101
#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION    1
#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION     2
#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION     3
#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION   4

#if ((ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION != SOME_VERSION) || \
     (ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION != SOME_OTHER_VERSION))
#error Versions do not match
    typedef int fix_this_compiler_error;
#else
    typedef int fix_this_compiler_error;
#endif
```

**MY_IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $release_num = "101p1p2p3p4";
my @array = split(/p/, $release_num);
my @versions;

for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@array); $i++)
{
    $versions[$i] = $array[$i];
}
print "array is : @versions \n";
print "0 : $versions[0] \n";
print "1 : $versions[1] \n";
print "2 : $versions[2] \n";
print "3 : $versions[3] \n";
print "4 : $versions[4] \n";

my $file = '/path/to/the/file/test_file.c';

`sed -i '/^\#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION/ c\\#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION      $versions[0]' $file`;
`sed -i '/^\#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION/ c\\#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION      $versions[1]' $file`;
`sed -i '/^\#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION/ c\\#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION      $versions[2]' $file`;
`sed -i '/^\#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION/ c\\#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION      $versions[3]' $file`;
`sed -i '/^\#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION/ c\\#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION      $versions[4]' $file`;
```

With my implementation I'm able to get the desired output as shown above , but want to understand that this is the right way to solve this problem or there can be a better method.

I asked similar question before but it was closed by moderators as i didn't share my work. I hope this question will not be closed because I've put an effort to propose a solution. Thanks!

Link to closed question: [How can i update a macro in a C file using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898328/how-can-i-update-a-macro-in-a-c-file-using-perl?noredirect=1#comment109613294_61898328)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $release_num = "101p1p2p3p4";
my @versions    = split(/p/, $release_num);
my $file        = "test_file.c";
my $backext     = "";

{
    local ($^I, @ARGV) = ($backext, $file);
    while (<>) {
        s/#define ALPHA_MAJOR_VERSION\s+\K\d+/$versions[0]/;
        s/#define ALPHA_MINOR_VERSION\s+\K\d+/$versions[1]/;
        s/#define BETA_MAJOR_VERSION\s+\K\d+/$versions[2]/;
        s/#define BETA_MINOR_VERSION\s+\K\d+/$versions[3]/;
        s/#define DELTA_BRANCH_VERSION\s+\K\d+/$versions[4]/;
        print;
    }
}
1;
```

Running external commands (as you did with `sed`) is unnecessary. External commands add the expensive overhead of process forking when Perl can accomplish the task that the external command would.

The `$^I` turns on in-place editing. It emulates Perl's `-i` switch. The file or files to be acted upon come from `@ARGV` as read by the `<>` operator. For good practice, we localize action with these entities by creating a block with bounding braces and declare local variables. If you set `$backext` an empty string, no backup copy will be preserved, otherwise the string will be appended to the original file name and the original file preserved.

The use of `\K` in the substitution keeps the text to the left of the match. This allows the original space between the define and the value to be preserved.

I use the final `1;` as a marker for the end of a script's code. It is immaterial unless you are writing a package or module. In that case, a the file must return true as its last statement for a `require` or `use` directive to be successful.

Comment: Thanks @JRFerguson. Even i didn't want to use `sed` in my solution hence sought feedback in this forum. Your solution is very crisp and doesn't use any external command. However, i don't want to  have a backup file because as a next step in the script,  i have to commit my changes (usually lot of files >100) in a git repository. If I set ` $backext` to `undef`, the file is printed on `STDOUT` but `test_file.c` is not updated. Also i want to understand the need of parenthesis as they are not part of any subroutine. And the need of `1;` in the last line.

Comment: Can you provide more explanation to this : `local ($^I, @ARGV)`. I'm unable to understand it.

Comment: @Yash, it emulates `perl -i.bck -pe'...' test_file.c`.  See perlvar for `$^I` and perlrun for `-i`. `@ARGV` is the command line arguments, which `<>` (short for `readline(ARGV)`) uses. See perlvar for `@ARGV` and `ARGV`

Comment: @Yash Yes, setting `$backext` to `undef` should have been an empty string. When undefined, in-place editing is disabled. Sorry, my bad.